# I want to implement select and scroll the window without touching scroll bar using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose an user wants to select all the content from a webpage, he/she selects and start dragging the pointer to the bottom edge of the window. Now who can we make the webpage scroll down.

Comment: just for understanding, you mean something similar to the action that happens pressing the mouse's wheel button on any scrollable page?

Answer (score 0):

If someone starts scrolling the page by selecting some text then it's the responsibility of the window to scroll down. If you want to make some `scrolling` events then you might have to use `window.scrollTo` method.

```js
function scrollWin() {
  window.scrollTo(200, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
  width: 5000px;
}
</style>

<body>
<h1>The Window Object</h1>
<h2>The scrollTo() Method</h2>

<p>Click to scroll the document.</p>

<button onclick="scrollWin()" style="position:fixed">Scroll to 200 horizontally!</button><br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now what can we do to mimic the above thing on a custom object. Suppose we have a canvas, Inside that we want to select some content and we want the canvas to scroll while selection if the cursor hits the edge.